# How do you set a views opacity to anywhere between 100% and 0% in Android?

Tags: android, view, opacity

I've got a view i'd like to set the opacity of. Eclipse tells me i can use any value between 0 and 1 but 0.5 for instance wont work since it has the data type double.

```
v.setAlpha(1);
```

The data type needs to be float, but im am not sure what that means. How would i set the opacity to 50% for example?

Thanks.

Comment: u can just force the float if you need, 0.5f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 50% it's

```
v.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

As 1% is just 1/100.